# Refresh .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG while editing the commit message

Tags: git, vim

Maybe someone knows how to be able to refresh git diff message while editing this in VIM, after changing git files.

Doing :e doesn't help much.

Thanks,
Ivan.

Answer (score 5):

As Git creates the message template and then invokes Vim, you cannot update it without leaving Vim and restarting the commit.

Quit Vim with `:cquit!`, so that the exit status conveys your intention to cancel, then retrigger the Git commit (e.g. by recalling the last command from the shell history via `!!`).